# OrderBy boolean value with AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to be able to sort by whether a variable is true or false.

Let's say we have a variable like so:

```
groups = {
    { name: 'first', value: true },
    { name: 'second', value: false },
    { name: 'third', value: true },
    { name: 'fourth', value: false }
}
```

And we can loop through it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    {{group.name}} {{group.value}}
</div>
```

Which will give you the following:

```
first true
second false
third true
fourth false
```

But if I wanted to *sort by a boolean value* then I could do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:{value:true}">
    {{group.name}} {{group.value}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:{value:false}">
    {{group.name}} {{group.value}}
</div>
```

Which would give me the following output (which I want):

```
first true    
third true
second false
fourth false
```

Is there a way to do this using `orderBy` or `filter` in a single `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Did you tried `"ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:'value'"`

Comment: Did you tried to use `orderBy` filter or it doesn't work well for boolean values? It is not clear from your question..

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was simply a case of switching round the variable names and not having the object name in. I had `orderBy:'-group.value':true` but it should have been `orderBy:'-value':true`.

Answer (score 11):

orderBy accepts and sorts by booleans.

Order the repeated element by the the 'value' property of 'group':

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: 'value'"
```

This will reverse the order:

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: '-value'"
```

If you would like to also sort by the 'name' property of 'group':

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: ['value','name']"
```

Answer (score 4):

use variable name instead obeject

```
orderBy:'Event':false
```

you will get the desired output like -

```
first true    
third true
second false
fourth false
```

Comment: What is 'Event' in this case?