# ng-repeat with filter using textbox always resets?

Tags: angularjs

i use ng-repeat as i populate the names

this is my view

```
<div ng-controller="user_tagging_ctl" ng-init="user_type='<?php if(isset($user_type))echo $user_type; else echo'all'; ?>';">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user_srch" maxlength="35" placeholder="Project Manager" required>
        <span class="user_tagging_container">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in data | filter:user_srch | orderBy:['status','x.user_lname']" data-id="{{x.user_id}}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="pm-group">
                {{x.user_fname + ' ' + x.user_lname}}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
```

everytime i search using my textbox the checkbox button resets to false.

example: i check the name i want then try to search another name then if i clear the textbox, all checkbox are now false/not checked.

how can i preserved the checked ones and make them at the orders first those are checked?

Answer (score 0):

Bind to ng-model:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pm-group" ng-model="x.selected">
```

See [how to order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378689/orderby-boolean-value-with-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Comment: hi, what i want is.. preserve the checked names,,because if i check one of the names then try to search again other names, then upon populating again the names. the checkbox is not checked,